# SQL: Only show values depending on contents

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is a complicated question so please bear with me. So I have the table below:

```
╔══════════╦═══════╦════════════╗
║ MasterID ║ SubID ║  Location  ║
╠══════════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║      100 ║    50 ║ California ║
║      100 ║    45 ║ Texas      ║
║      100 ║    40 ║ California ║
║       99 ║    29 ║ California ║
║       99 ║    28 ║ Texas      ║
║       99 ║    28 ║ California ║
║       98 ║    15 ║ Texas      ║
║       98 ║    15 ║ Texas      ║
║       97 ║     5 ║ California ║
╚══════════╩═══════╩════════════╝
```

.

And I want to display every MasterID, SubID, and Location where the Location is California. However, here's the catch. **I don't want those things displayed unless, within each MasterID, every SubID has a California Location.**

Where MasterID = 100, I would not want anything displayed, because there is a Texas, with its own SubID, within that MasterID.

Where MasterID = 99, I would want all 3 columns displayed, because, although there is a Texas under that MasterID, there is also a California within the same SubID.

98 is not good because it has SubIDs that contain only Texas.

97 is ok because it's just California.

The desired table outcome is this:

```
╔══════════╦═══════╦════════════╗
║ MasterID ║ SubID ║  Location  ║
╠══════════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║       99 ║    29 ║ California ║
║       99 ║    28 ║ Texas      ║
║       99 ║    28 ║ California ║
║       97 ║     5 ║ California ║
╚══════════╩═══════╩════════════╝
```

(Removing 99......28.....Texas is fine too)

Comment: So, what is your question?  What have you already tried?

Comment: If I run it now, for example I'd say Select From... Where Location LIKE 'California'. But then it would show the IDs I don't want. In this example, it would show MasterID 100, SubID 50 and 40, while essentially hiding the SubID 45 Texas value there. If there is that Texas SubID, I don't want any of those columns displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM dbo.YourTable A
INNER JOIN (SELECT  MasterID,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT SubID) SubIDs,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Location = 'California' THEN SubID END) CaliforniaSubIDs
            FROM dbo.YourTable
            GROUP BY MasterID) B
    ON A.MasterID = B.MasterID
WHERE B.SubIDs = B.CaliforniaSubIDs;
```

**[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/522672/q1)** you can see the query in action. And the results are:

```
╔══════════╦═══════╦════════════╗
║ MasterID ║ SubID ║  Location  ║
╠══════════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║       97 ║     5 ║ California ║
║       99 ║    29 ║ California ║
║       99 ║    28 ║ Texas      ║
║       99 ║    28 ║ California ║
╚══════════╩═══════╩════════════╝
```

**UPDATE**

To do what you explained in your comment, you can use:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  A.*,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MasterID, SubID
                                   ORDER BY CASE WHEN Location LIKE '%Cali%'
                                            OR Location LIKE '%fornia%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
                                            Location)
    FROM dbo.YourTable A
    INNER JOIN (SELECT  MasterID,
                        COUNT(DISTINCT SubID) SubIDs,
                        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Location = 'California' THEN SubID END) CaliforniaSubIDs
                FROM dbo.YourTable
                GROUP BY MasterID) B
        ON A.MasterID = B.MasterID
    WHERE B.SubIDs = B.CaliforniaSubIDs;
)
SELECT MasterID, SubID, Location
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: That's amazing , thanks so much! I've noticed that out of around 500 entries 2 of them were incorrectly deleted, so I'll look into that. Probably something I messed up somewhere. Anyway thanks again!

Comment: Hey I know it's been a week but I have a follow up question... So assuming that under one MasterID there is one SubID with multiple locations - is there a way to only display one of those locations? Even better would be to set preferences for which to display, for example: If the location contains "Cali" or "fornia", show that one, but if neither of those exist just showing Texas is fine. If you know how to do that I'd be super grateful if you could help me again!

Comment: Also this is going straight into excel so if you know that better that's fine too. I was thinking of something about removing duplicates but I don't know how to do that and give preferences for what to remove

Comment: @sg4 you know, I'm not sure if I can help you, but you could tell me what database engine and version you are using

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL server 2012. It's totally fine if you don't know though!